# What is the circular dependency here?

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting a circular dependency error:
`Circular dependency found: $notificationService <- $notificationService <- $uiService <- $tourService`

- `$notificationService` only depends on `$rootScope`
- `$uiService` depends on a few things including `$notificationService` but NOT `$rootScope` and NOT `$tourService`
- `$tourService` depends on many things including `$notificationService` and `$uiService` but NOT `$rootScope`

As far as I can tell there is no circular dependency and definitely not the one described in the error.

notification.service.ts:

```
export class NotificationService {
  static $inject = ['$rootScope'];
  constructor(private $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService) {...}

  ...

}

export default function(mod: ng.IModule) {
  mod.service('$notificationService', NotificationService);
}
```

I don't see how `$notificationService` could be involved in any circular dependency since it only relies on `$rootScope`.

Comment: How are you importing the `$notification` service? Show the code for that.

Comment: Just coming after a large refactor, I found we have two different services both named, `$notificationService`.  Probably a copy error.  I'm surprised AngularJS wouldn't give a different error on redeclaring a service with the same name.